# Dynamically adding elements to a lightbox (Venobox) gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have several [Venobox](http://veno.es/venobox/) galleries on the same page. Some galleries have hundreds of photos and that's why I only show the first 3 thumbnails of each gallery.

```
<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore1" title="" data-gall="gal1" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-1" href="/show.php?pid=1"><img src="thumb1.jpg" /></a>
<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore1" title="" data-gall="gal1" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-1" href="/show.php?pid=2"><img src="thumb2.jpg" /></a>
<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore1" title="" data-gall="gal1" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-1" href="/show.php?pid=3"><img src="thumb3.jpg" /></a>

<div class="hidden showmore1"></div>

<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore2" title="" data-gall="gal2" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-2" href="/show.php?pid=4"><img src="thumb4.jpg" /></a>
<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore2" title="" data-gall="gal2" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-2" href="/show.php?pid=5"><img src="thumb5.jpg" /></a>
<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore2" title="" data-gall="gal2" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-2" href="/show.php?pid=6"><img src="thumb6.jpg" /></a>

<div class="hidden showmore2"></div>
```

When an user starts to view some gallery (clicks on any thumbnail), the clicked image must appear and the script in the background must load all the thumbnails (links to the images) of this gallery:

```
<div class="hidden showmore1">
<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore1" title="" data-gall="gal1" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-1" href="/show.php?pid=7"><img src="thum7.jpg" /></a>
<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore1" title="" data-gall="gal1" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-1" href="/show.php?pid=8"><img src="thumb8.jpg" /></a>
<a class="venobox loadmore loadmore1" title="" data-gall="gal1" data-vbtype="ajax" data-bid="x-y-z-1" href="/show.php?pid=9"><img src="thumb9.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

**The problem**

When I click on any thumbnail, the script loads the rest of the images but doesn't show the clicked image. I can click only on newly loaded thumbnails but can not click on any of the first three thumbnails. At the same time when I open a newly loaded image and click on the "previous" arrow, I can see the first 3 photos as well.

All this work with PrettyPhoto script but PrettyPhoto is not responsive, so I decided to implement Venobox but have this problem.

**The script:**

```
jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(function(){ 

  var handler = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var dbid = $(this).attr("data-bid");
    var myarr = dbid.split("-");
    var ftip = myarr[0];
    var fnum = myarr[1];
    var falb = myarr[2];
    var fpoid = myarr[3];
    var order_by = myarr[4];

    if($(this).hasClass('loadmore')) { 
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/loadmore.php",
        data: {poid:fpoid,alb:falb,typ:ftip,num:fnum,order_by:order_by},   
        success: function(d){  

          $('#showmore'+fpoid).html(d);  
          $('.loadmore'+fpoid).removeClass('loadmore'); //removing class so that new images load only once 

          $("a[data-gall^='gal"+fpoid+"'").venobox(); //reactivating venobox
          $("a[data-gall^='gal"+fpoid+"'").filter("a[href='" + href + "']").click();

        }
      });
    }  
  }
})});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [venobox](http://veno.es/venobox/); the way to trigger click is
    $("#firstlink").venobox().trigger('click');

also there are Callbacks you can use for above code (details in above link)